# Is the ordering of props in JSX important?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs, spread-syntax

If the `o` object contains a key/value pair of: `foo: 'bar'` can I depend on these outcomes?:

```
// foo will be 'bar'
<MyComponent
    foo='should not override'
    {...o}
  />

// foo will be 'overridden'
<MyComponent
    {...o}
    foo='overridden'
  />
```

In other words, is the ordering of properties while using the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) operator significant?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes, it is. It works exactly as your example says

You example is translated into:

```
// foo will be 'bar'
<MyComponent
    {/* ...other 'o' keys/values...*/}
    foo='should not override'
    {/* ...other 'o' keys/values...*/}
    foo='bar'
/>

// foo will be 'overridden'
<MyComponent
    foo='bar'
    {/* ...other 'o' keys/values...*/}
    foo='overridden'
    {/* ...other 'o' keys/values...*/}
/>
```

And therefore, it overrides always the last one

Answer (score 7):

Yes, ordering does matter. The exact reason is how Babel transpiles the JSX. You can see this in the [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=DwWQngwg9gtgDlAdgU0QFwAQDMpQLwBEUAbsgE5kCWAJtagRgN4B0rUAvgHwBQ3wA9OGjwkqNJyA):

```
<MyComponent foo="should not override" {...o}>

</MyComponent>
```

Becomes:

```
React.createElement(MyComponent, _extends({ foo: "overridden" }, o));
```

Where `_extends` is just [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), or if the browser doesn't support it, `_extends` is functionally the same. Per the MDN documentation:

> **Properties in the target object will be overwritten by properties in the sources if they have the same key.** Later sources' properties will similarly overwrite earlier ones.

(Emphasis is mine). Thus, when `Object.assign` is used to pass props to the component, the target is `{ foo: "overridden" }` and the source is `o`. Since `foo` exists in both the target and the source, `foo` in the target is overridden. This also applies to:

```
<MyComponent {...o} foo="overridden">

</MyComponent>
```

Here, the JSX is transpiled to the opposite:

```
React.createElement(MyComponent, _extends({}, o, { foo: "overriden" }));
```

It's a bit different because here, the target is an empty object, but the latter half of the quote from MDN applies. The sources here are `o` and `{ foo: "overridden" }`. Since `foo` exists in both sources, the `foo` in source `{ foo: "overridden" }` overwrite's the `foo` from `o`.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this sandboxed proof:

https://codesandbox.io/s/Q1GMx9KM9

As you can see it behaves exactly as you theorized in your question.

**EDIT**
SO Snippet:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.foo}</div>
  }
}

const styles = {
  fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
  textAlign: 'center',
};

const o = { foo: 'bar' };

const App = () =>
  <div style={styles}>
    <h2>Spreading after explicit property</h2>
    <MyComponent foo="will be overriden" {...o} />
    <h2>Spreading before explicit property</h2>
    <MyComponent {...o} foo="was overriden" />
  </div>;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a runnable implementation. Running your code helped more than reading the whole discussion :)